# FCM Background handling in Flutter - iOS

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, background-process, flutter-ios

**What I want to achieve**

I'm implementing FCM in flutter for iOS in such a way that in every state (foreground, background and terminated) when the notification is received, we need to show an alert with sound on the screen for some time (Say 2 mnts).

**What is clear**

Implementation is clear when the app is in foreground which can easily be done using `onMessage` callback.

**Where is the issue**

The confusion is with background and terminated part:

1. How to detect in the background that notification is received (I
   know on Resume is called when we click on the notification in the
   notification try). But we need to show alert on notification arrival
   not on Clicking the notification.
2. How to detect when the app is terminated(I know onLaunch is called
   when we click on the notification in the notification tray) But we
   need to show alert on notification arrival not on Clicking the
   notification.
3. Is it possible to show any system alert when the app is not running
   like when notification is received while app is terminated and we
   show a customized alert like Alarm alert on the screen.
4. There is onBackgroundMessage call back but I don't know if it works
   for iOS (as documentation is more focused on Android settings in
   onBackgroundMessage call back part).

Comment: For me when app is in background or terminated, the system tray is handling the notifications, so that works well. I am not even sure what onBackgroundMessage is for since system tray does that when app in background/terminated